# Android not executing onRestart when returning from Processing Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, processing, android-lifecycle

I have a problem with one application that i am working on, when i call a [Processing](http://processing.org/) activity from one android activity, it works fine an i can see the processing thing with out a problem, but when i click the back button to go to the previous activity, is empty.

I run a few test and i realized that the onrestart and onresume method are not being called.
so, my question would be, what are the factors that can make an activity to not execute those
steps.

**UPDATE:**

when i call a normal Android activity everything works as expected, when i return i see everything as it was before calling the activity, BUT when i execute a processing activity when i return all the objects in my layout are empty and the restart and resume methods are never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to call your NextActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);


@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(requestCode == REQ_CODE){

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                    //do something

        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){

                    //do something else

        }

    }

}
```

Inside NextActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
```

Comment: i already tried what you told me, and is still not working, for some reason the processing activities work different.